# Generate Gradient of Colors for chart

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor, ios-charts

I'm making a small pie chart, and I'd like to have each entry in the chart get lighter and lighter the smaller the pie slices get. I have to generate an array of `UIColor` to color the chart.

Here's what I have right now:

```swift
for i in 0..<entries.count {
    let percent = 1.0 - (CGFloat(i - 1)/CGFloat(entries.count))
    dataSet.colors.append(UIColor.systemPurple.withAlphaComponent(percent))
}
```

And it generates this:
[image: bad example of pie chart]

I'd like the colors in the chart to be more like this: (sorry I just quick made it in google sheets as an example)
[image: good pie chart]

Any ideas?

Comment: your formula let percent = 1.0 - (CGFloat(i - 1)/CGFloat(entries.count)) is weird for me, try check percent value for each loop

Comment: I'll give it a go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this solution.

```
var initialAlpha = 1.0

for i in 0..<entries.count { 
    dataSet.colors.append(UIColor.systemPurple.withAlphaComponent(initialAlpha))
    initialAlpha -= 0.1
}
```

You can also change the difference value of 0.1 to any fraction value let's say 0.15 or 0.2 etc. according to your requirement.

Comment: Good idea, I'll try it and get back to you

Comment: This worked! I ended up making the amount subtracted a proportion of the set's items to the total percent like this: `initialAlpha -= CGFloat(1)/CGFloat(entries.count)`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a different color model like HSB, and vary one or more of those settings between colors. In your case it looks like you're using a bright purple and want to vary the saturation from 100% to 0%.

You could then create your colors using the UIColor initializer `init(hue:saturation:brightness:alpha:)`

In tinkering with it a little bit, colors with a hue of 300, 100% brightness, and saturation values of 100%, 80%, 60%, 40%, 20% and 0% looked decent.